# Getting some warning messages while building thr angular application

Tags: angular, angular-formbuilder

I am getting the following error while building the angular application using the command `ng build --prod`.

**Error:**

```
edit.component.html(111,50): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
edit.component.html(113,54): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<div *ngIf="storeForm.get('Address').controls['AddressLine1'].invalid && (storeForm.get('Address').controls['AddressLine1'].dirty || storeForm.get('Address').controls['AddressLine1'].touched)"
                                            class="alert alert-danger">
<div *ngIf="storeForm.get('Address').controls['AddressLine1'].errors.required">
                                                    AddressLine1 is required.
     </div>
</div>

this.storeForm = this.fb.group({
      Address: this.fb.group({
        AddressLine1: ['', Validators.required],

      }),

    });
```

I need to ignore those warning messages while building the application and I am using `Angular cli-8.2.1`.

Comment: Take a look at here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the working solution -

.ts file

```
myForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      testimonials: new FormArray([])
    });

    this.getInitialForms();
}

// THIS IS IMPORTANT
// getter  - (accessed as this.testimonialsForm in this file)
get testimonialsForm() { return this.myForm.get('testimonials') as FormArray; }

getInitialForms() {
    this.testimonialsForm.push(
        this.fb.group({
         name: ['', Validators.required],
         designation: ['', Validators.required],
         testimonial_text: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    );
 }
```

And in template file **instead of**

```
myForm.get('testimonials').controls
```

**use this**

```
testimonialsForm.controls
```

**I was getting the same error with angular 8 and it worked perfectly fine for me.**

Please let me know if you any issues.